# Coroutine problem, I don't know what's happening

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

> Calling function.

```
 private const int deathHangTime = 2;   
 private void Die()
    {
          Debug.Log("1 " + Time.time);
          StartCoroutine(DelayForTime(deathHangTime));
          Debug.Log("4 " + Time.time);
    }
```

> Coroutine

```
IEnumerator DelayForTime(float time)
{
     Debug.Log("2 " + Time.time);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
     Debug.Log("3 " + Time.time);
}
```

[image]

Why doesn't it wait for 2 seconds?
Why doesn't it print the 3rd Debug line?

Comment: [You're making the same mistake as this previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/154298/39518), assuming that a function has to wait for the coroutine it started to finish before it keeps executing. That's not how StartCoroutine works. It queues-up the coroutine to continue executing later, then immediately returns to the calling function to let it finish. You cannot use a coroutine to inject a delay into a non-coroutine function. Put anything you want to delay inside the coroutine.

Comment: As for why the third debug doesn't print, it's likely that either the delay is longer than you waited for, or something destroyed/disabled this script instance before the coroutine was ready to resume, aborting it. We'd need to see more of your code to help you debug that part.