# How to temporarily set a game object active?

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

I'm trying to an use IEnumerator method called Wait() to temporarily enable and then wait, and disable a gameobject within a method. Basically I'm trying to create a muzzle flash within a shoot method, but whenever I add the muzzle.SetActive(false) to the method, it never activates in the first place. This code should work right?

```
void Shoot()
{
    muzzle.SetActive(true);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

        Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.TakeDamage(damage);
        }
    }
    Wait((float).1);
    muzzle.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: [As explained here, you cannot use a coroutine to insert a delay into a non-coroutine method](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/154300/39518). `Shoot` is a synchronous, non-coroutine method. It can only execute all at once in a single frame. Calling an IEnumerator in the middle does not change that. You can make a coroutine "WaitThenDisableMuzzleFlash" and start it with `StartCoroutine(WaitThenDisableMuzzleFlash(0.1f))` at the end of `Shoot`, so `Shoot` can return without disabling the muzzle flash. Turning it off is then delegated to the coroutine, which *can* wait for a later frame.

Comment: I appreciate your help @DMGregory